# How to add file to Eclipse project that already exists

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

The team is using Android Studio to develop Android projects.  But researching Unit Tests, it looks like the support for JUnit Test Cases is in Eclipse.  After exporting a test project from Eclipse and importing it into Android Studio I was under the mistaken impression that I could go back and forth.  But when I added a java class to the project in Android Studio, the new java class does not show up in the Eclipse project.

I could import the new class if I wanted to move it to a different location first.  So, is there any way to get the Eclipse project to recognize the file on disk should be included in the project?

Comment: Why not just stay inside Studio?  Put the cursor on a class name.  Press CTRL-SHIFT-T.

Comment: I'll try that.  If it works, I'll let you know so you can answer the question and get a point for it.  :-)

Comment: @Simon I found a guide on making tests with a Gradle project. [Android Gradle user Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing).  I'm not sure I posted that link correctly....  Anyway, I do not have a src/instrumentTest/ folder in my project.  Is there some basic configuration step that I am missing here?  Otherwise, CMD-SHIFT-T on the mac does it.  Thank you.